# Map taggable_friends to friends

Tags: facebook

I'm building a Facebook-connected app, and I have the following issue. You tag your friends in the app (which I can do with taggable_friends), and the goal is that that would prompt some people to install the app. However, once that person joins (and is visible in `/friends`), I don't see any way to know the numeric id of the tagged friend. Is there a way to do this mapping without guessing? Example follows.

```
1. User 100123 tags their friend (taggable_friends id 'AbCdEf')
2. That friend joins my app and is given id 100124.
3. ?? Here I'd like to know that 'AbCdEf' and 100124 are the same person. 
      Is that possible?
```

Comment: No it is not possible. What do you need it for?

Comment: With the app that I'm building, users need to be able to see all the times that they've been tagged. With the current setup, there doesn't seem to be any way to do that.